# Calling special <a href> properties in ASP.NET code behind, Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website developed using the twitter bootstrap and asp.net. Bootstrap has modal window controls built in to it that can be accessed using an  tag that looks like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#catalogItemModal">Details</a>
```

The data-toggle property is the important part here and is required to get the modal window to display properly. I want to redirect to this url in the code behind. Is there a way to redirect from aspx.cs and preserve the data-toggle property?

UPDATE:
I ended up using a jQuery function to do the code behind work that I needed to accomplish before displaying the modal window and was able to simply bind it to the onclick event of the  tag which allows me to preserve the data-toggle attribute.

Should have gone with that first. If anyone ever stumbles across this question and thinks they need help with something similar feel free to inbox message me and I will share details on how I accomplished this.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do here. How do you intend to show the popup (modal, I assume) and redirect the page? Do you want to show the popup after the redirect?

Comment: I don't actually need to redirect the page at all. The modal div is already there I just want to navigate to the #catalogItemModal anchor that already exists on the page using code behind but the data-toggle="modal" needs to be included somehow in order for the modal window to properly display.

Answer (score 0):

To access the element in the server side, you need to make it runat="server". After that you should be able to access the attribute using the control.Attributes["data-toggle'] in C#

```
<a id="lnkDetails" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" href="#catalogItemModal">Details</a
```

C# Code

```
string toggleAttribute = lnkDetails..Attributes["data-toggle'];
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have been more clear. I don't have an <a> tag at all. I am working with a LinkButton inside a repeater control. When the LinkButton is clicked I want to redirect (using Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer or whatever) TO that link but I somehow need to include the data-toggle attribute in order for the popup to display.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a jQuery function to do the code behind work that I needed to accomplish before displaying the modal window and was able to simply bind it to the onclick event of the  tag.

Should have gone with that first. If anyone ever stumbles across this question and thinks they need help with something similar feel free to inbox message me and I will share